# Cleanest way to format a float to a string w/ decimal point and single digit, rounded down in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I want these floats:

`[0.000, 0.100, 0.200, 0.300, 0.400. 0.500, 0.600, 0.700, 0.800, 0.900]`

to map to these strings:

`[".0", ".1", ".2", ".3", ".4". ".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"]`

I've found a solution that's close but doesn't quite work completely. e.g. using `0.100`:

```
let num = NSNumber(value: 0.100)

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.roundingMode = .down

formatter.string(from: num) // -> "0.1"
```

But this doesn't work for `0.000` // returns `"0"` not `".0"`.

Is there a solution that's cleaner/simpler than the 99% solution above that would also prevent me from doing a check to prepend a decimal if the value is `0`?

Comment: Add 1 more line and you are good: `formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1`

Comment: Aha! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve this without having any digits before the decimal point and rounding to 1 digit after the decimal point, use the following:

```
import Foundation

let formatter = NumberFormatter()

func createFormat(num: NSNumber) -> String {
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 0
    formatter.roundingMode = .down
    return formatter.string(from: num)!
}

createFormat(num: 0.000) // -> ".0"
createFormat(num: 0.500) // -> ".5"
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
String(format: "%.1f", floatValue)
```

would give you "0.1" where %.1f represents the number of precision digits (%.2f for 2 digits ect')

and if you want to also calculate round down (to 2 digits for example):

```
      let precision = 2
      floatValue *= pow(10, Double(precision))
      floatValue = float.rounded(.down)
      floatValue /= pow(10, Double(precision))
```